# Context.isPointInPath usage

Tags: html, canvas

I googled for this but didn't find any example that uses `Context.isPointInPath` in HTML 5.

I know it's supposed to return me true if the point is on the current path, but how exactly do you use it? Should you use it in between `context.beginPath()` and `cotext.closePath()` (or fill* for that matter)

I tried this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(0,0, 100,100);
ctx.isPointInPath(50,50); // Returned false
ctx.isPointInPath(50,0);  // Tried it on the actual path, not the filled region, returned false
ctx.isPointInPath(50,8);  // My canvas had the default 8 offset, returned false
ctx.isPointInPath(50,9);  // Canvas had a border of 1px, returned false
```

I don't know what went wrong, but all of them returned false and I never had one returning true.

Finally, I closed the path and checked for the values, still returned false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of your calls to `isPointInPath()` are returning false because you aren't actually creating any paths when you are working with your context. The `fillRect()` function doesn't create a path. It just fills in some pixels on your canvas with whatever color you previously specified.

Instead, you will want to use one of the path-modifying functions, such as `rect()` or `moveTo()`. For all the details on `isPointInPath()` and the path functions, refer to the canvas spec here:

isPointInPath(): http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath

path functions: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#complex-shapes-%28paths%29

Comment: I was under the impression that fillRect first creates a rect and then fills it up. You cleared it up, thank you. It works well now.